# In Moq, given a reference to the .Object, is it possible to manipulate the original mock?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I was hoping that it was possible to manipulate the `.Object`as a mock via extension methods in Moq but I have not found any applicable extension methods.

For example:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

/* ... */

var mock = Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Verify(x => x.Bar());

IFoo foo = mock.Object;
foo.Verify(x => x.Bar());   // this does not compile!
```

Is there anyway that I can write code like on the line above (the one that does not compile?) If not, why not?

Comment: How can it compile? IFoo doesn't have a Verify method

Comment: @MikeSW - via some extension method perhaps? Rhino Mocks allows it ...

Comment: Do you have an extension method 'Verify' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use `Mock.Get<T>` which *Retrieves the mock object for the given object instance*:

```
Mock.Get(foo).Verify(x => x.Bar());
```